# rstrip() not working as expected

Tags: python

I have written following python code. What i am expecting it to do is add a random word from the file "noise" to each line of "raw" and print it to the file "dataset"

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from random import randint

raw = open("raw_dataset_1", "r")
noise = open("random", "r")
dataset = open("raw_noisy", "w")

lines = noise.readlines()

for line in raw:
    a = randint(1, 5449)
    addNoise = lines[a-1]
    #print a
    #print addNoise
    noisy = (line + addNoise)
    noisy1= noisy.rstrip()
    #print noisy1
    dataset.write(noisy1)
```

My expected "dataset" file is :

```
city mountain sky sun chalk
bay lake sun tree discussions
beach sea sky sun background
```

But i'm getting:

```
city mountain sky sun 
chalk
bay lake sun tree 
discussions
beach sea sky sun 
background
```

Can someone please point out my mistake?

Comment: What are the contents of your input file?

Comment: each line of the "raw" file contains a set of words. each line of "noise" contains a single word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While reading each line using:

```
for line in raw:
```

`line` contains the newline at the end. You need to remove it.

Try using:

```
noisy = line.rstrip() + " " + addNoise
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to do `noisy = (line.rstrip("\n") + " " + addNoise)`

I tested it and it worked for me.